# Commerce minimum quantity and purchase multiplier

Tags: commerce

I have added a field to content type **Product** with the purchase quantity (default 1). Products can only be purchased by this quantity. For example, if its value is 5, you could buy 5, 10, 15, and so on. This is configured by products, and some products could have a value of 1, and others could have a value greater than 1.
After read some post about ["quantities"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141864/commerce-and-attribute-quantities) and ["minimum quantity"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/147672/set-minimun-quantity-in-product-drupal-commerce), I haven't found how to do it. I have tried with some modules like [Commerce Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra), and [Commerce Add to Cart Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras). But without success.
Could some one give me some ideas how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's [answer on this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141864/commerce-and-attribute-quantities) is the approach you'd want to take:

1. Install [Commerce Custom Product](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product).
2. Create a new line item type that has new quantity select field and widget. Expose this to the add to cart form.
3. Hide the regular quantity selection to the add to cart form.
4. Use a rule to take the value in the field you created in step 2 and set the quantity field to that value on the line item.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I have read this answer before posting my question, and I think It isn't the same case (or perhaps I didn't understand this solution). In my case, the user can set a value, for example 5, and only multiple of it (10, 15, 20, ...) but he can't buy, for example 3. This value must be configured product by product and could be different.